# TOP command overall CPU

Tags: performance, postgresql, load, cpu, rhel

I have below top command results in my RHEL 6. It's running PostgreSQL on my server.

I see 35.8% idle in CPU(s) while all the CPU usages below show 100%.

So how should I read below output?

```
top - 03:06:30 up 97 days, 20:15,  3 users,  load average: 10.85, 10.51, 10.13
Tasks: 738 total,  14 running, 724 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
**Cpu(s): 53.3%us,  9.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 35.8%id,  0.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st**
Mem:  32077620k total, 24335372k used,  7742248k free,    19084k buffers
Swap: 81919992k total,   407968k used, 81512024k free, 18686780k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
19171 enterpri  20   0 8590m 966m 951m R 100.0  3.1   6:24.51 edb-postgres
19588 enterpri  20   0 8590m 956m 941m R 100.0  3.1   1:20.51 edb-postgres
18494 enterpri  20   0 8590m 959m 944m R 99.8  3.1  18:18.75 edb-postgres
18683 enterpri  20   0 8588m 984m 975m R 99.8  3.1   6:22.80 edb-postgres
19158 enterpri  20   0 8592m 1.0g 1.0g R 99.8  3.3   5:40.16 edb-postgres
19167 enterpri  20   0 8589m 959m 945m R 99.8  3.1   7:48.53 edb-postgres
19590 enterpri  20   0 8586m 945m 933m R 99.8  3.0   2:51.32 edb-postgres
19591 enterpri  20   0 8588m 950m 936m R 99.8  3.0   3:07.77 edb-postgres
19592 enterpri  20   0 8589m 948m 935m R 99.8  3.0   2:52.66 edb-postgres
```

Comment: The output is illegible. Please re-paste and this time use the `{}` button to indent the output as a code block. Also, what PostgreSQL version?

Finally, this is off topic for Stack Overflow. I think you are looking for http://serverfault.com/ . I strongly suggest deleting this question and re-posting over there instead, after reading http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of CPUs (how many?) on your system.  Some of them are very busy running postgres, and some of them are not.

In your version of `top`, `%CPU` represents the percent of a single CPU, not the percent of the total system CPU.  If you had a threaded application, one entry could show more than 100%, but PostgreSQL is not threaded within a single process.